# How can I manipulate hundreds of thousands of rows of data without it freezing in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, power, power-query

When using an add in function in Excel to compute values for hundreds of thousands of rows of data, Excel will start freezing or showing "0" values.

[image]

The add in function allows me to calculate the mileage of an origin and destination pair for each row.

I've tried filtering by year, but am having issues with that even.

Are there any solutions to this?

Comment: Please show samples of the workbook and choose to `show formulas` so we can see how it is setup.

Comment: I assume your running a 64-bit version of Excel and have as much system memory as the system can support?

Comment: you are pushing up against the limits of desktop productivity software. at some point, you need a real DBMS.

Comment: @FrankThomas - I suggest that when a user is talking about "hundreds of thousands" of rows of data, they're well past "pushing the limits of desktop productivity software", and deep into "need a real DBMS".

Comment: Excel should be fine with hundreds of thousands if you're using Power Query. If you're using spreadsheet formulas, or an add-in of unknown efficiency, you're probably gonna have a bad time. If you edit your post with more details about where the calculations are happening, we may be able to help.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/excel/concepts/excel-performance/excel-improving-calculation-performance

Answer (score 1):

You need a relational database to deal with large amounts of data. Most of these DB's use the powerful *and* easy-to-learn [Structured Query Language (SQL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL).

Microsoft has the (hobbled) [*Access* DB in Office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access), free LibreOffice has [*Base*](https://help.libreoffice.org/6.2/en-US/text/shared/explorer/database/main.html), and [there are numerous others](https://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/free-database-software/). Even the huge commercial Oracle database is free for personal use. *Base* probably has the smallest learning curve, includes both back-end (DB engine) and front-end (GUI), and might be a good tool to learn with.

Using *Excel* with large data sets is like trying to move Aconcagua with a [Tonka Toy](https://www.target.com/p/tonka-steel-classics-bull-dozer/-/A-79391471).

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using another tool to manipulate such a large dataset. Consider looking into R (https://posit.co/download/rstudio-desktop/)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).